# JQuery '.ui-icon-script' not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/248mY/)

The JS:

```
$('p').button({icons: {secondary: '.ui-icon-script'}});
```

I don't know what's wrong...but on the jquery theme I downloaded, it has an example of a script icon. When I try it myself, the icon doesn't show as the script icon, it shows as `'.ui-icon-carat-1-n'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class name is `ui-icon-script`, not `.ui-icon-script`.

http://jsfiddle.net/FKZL6/

Comment: No, the *selector* is `.ui-icon-foo` but the class *name* is `ui-icon-foo`. Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller